# Show parent and child folders in the same File Explorer window in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is this possible? I am writing up an explanation of something. It would be really helpful to show a visual description of how the folder tree is supposed to look. The ideal way to do that would be to have an explorer window that shows grandparent, parent, and child folders and their contents. What I really want to do is to show three generations. But file explorer only wants to show one level at a time, as best I can tell.

Comment: If you go to the parent directory and enter `.` or `*` in the search box then you will get a flat list. You may want to click on the **Folder** column to group subdirectories together, and you can drag the folder column to the beginning of the list columns.

Comment: In File/Windows Explorer's navigation pane, you can expand the "+" symbols and get a folder tree on the left hand side of your window. You can then drag the tree to the right to make it wider. In Options, you can also automatically enabling expanding the folder tree to your current directory. This is probably the easiest option

Comment: You can show all the folders in one view  as explained by InterLinked, but not the contents of all the folders, this would require 3rd party software of some sort.

Answer (score -1):

It's not an explorer window, but `tree /f` (from a cmd prompt) might give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: Answer is specifically looking for an answer with Windows Explorer.